# Unable to start server connection channel

Tags: ibm-mq

We have been using Websphere MQ 8.0.0.2 on windows machine.
We have configured server connection setup.

We are unable to start server connection channel since channel is in inactive state.

While application tried to pull the msg from queue, the SVRCONN channel went to inactive state.
I have checked ip/port number and channel name at client end, all are same as in server side.

Below errors are logged in qmgr error logs.
Error log:

```
12/28/2017 15:12:27 - Process(24316.247) User(SWIFTAMHMQ) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(HYDSWIFTMQ2T1) Installation(AMHMQ)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.2) QMgr(SWIFTBACKOFFICE)

AMQ9492: The TCP/IP responder program encountered an error.

EXPLANATION:
The responder program was started but detected an error. 

The host name was '10.24.187.121'; in some cases the host name cannot be
determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages in the error files to determine the error
encountered by the responder program. 
----- amqrmrsa.c : 921 --------------------------------------------------------
12/28/2017 15:21:09 - Process(24316.603) User(SWIFTAMHMQ) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(HYDSWIFTMQ2T1) Installation(AMHMQ)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.2


AMQ9207: The data received from host '10.24.187.121' on channel '????' is not
valid.

EXPLANATION:
Incorrect data format received from host '10.24.187.121' over TCP/IP. It may be
that an unknown host is attempting to send data. 

An FFST file might be generated containing the invalid data received. It will
not be generated if this is the beginning of a conversation with the remote
side, and the format is a simple known format (example: a GET request from an
HTTP web browser).  If you want to override this, to cause FFST files to be
written for any bad data, including simple known formats, then set the
environment variable AMQ_BAD_COMMS_DATA_FDCS=TRUE and restart the queue
manager. 

The channel name is '????'; in some cases it cannot be determined and so is
shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Tell the systems administrator. 

12/28/2017 15:21:09 - Process(24316.603) User(SWIFTAMHMQ) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(HYDSWIFTMQ2T1) Installation(AMHMQ)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.2) QMgr(SWIFTBACKOFFICE)

AMQ9207: The data received from host '10.24.187.121' on channel '????' is not
valid.

EXPLANATION:
Incorrect data format received from host '10.24.187.121' over TCP/IP. It may be
that an unknown host is attempting to send data. 

An FFST file might be generated containing the invalid data received. It will
not be generated if this is the beginning of a conversation with the remote
side, and the format is a simple known format (example: a GET request from an
HTTP web browser).  If you want to override this, to cause FFST files to be
written for any bad data, including simple known formats, then set the
environment variable AMQ_BAD_COMMS_DATA_FDCS=TRUE and restart the queue
manager. 
The channel name is '????'; in some cases it cannot be determined and so is
shown as '????'.
ACTION:
12/28/2017 15:21:09 - Process(24316.603) User(SWIFTAMHMQ) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(HYDSWIFTMQ2T1) Installation(AMHMQ)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.2) QMgr(SWIFTBACKOFFICE)

AMQ9492: The TCP/IP responder program encountered an error.

EXPLANATION:
The responder program was started but detected an error. 

The host name was '10.24.187.121'; in some cases the host name cannot be
determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages in the error files to determine the error
encountered by the responder program. 
----- amqrmrsa.c : 921 ------

FDC file are

UTC Time Offset   :- 330 ((UNKNOWN))                                                   |
| Operating System  :- Windows Ver 6.2 (7) Server Datacenter x64 Edition                                   |
| LVLS              :- 8.0.0.2                                                |
| Product Long Name :- WebSphere MQ for Windows (x64 platform)                |
| Vendor            :- IBM                                                    |
| O/S Registered    :- 1                                                      |
| Data Path         :- E:\MQServer\IBM\MQ                                     |
| Installation Path :- E:\MQServer\IBM\WebSphere MQ                           |
| Installation Name :- AMHMQ            (1)                                   |
| License Type      :- Production                                             |
| Probe Id          :- CO618000  
Application Name  :- MQM                                                    |
| Component         :- cciInvalidDataReceived                                 |
| SCCS Info         :- F:\build\slot1\p800_P\src\lib\comms\amqccita.c,        |
| Line Number       :- 4309                                                   |
| Build Date        :- Feb 17 2015                                            |
| Build Level       :- p800-002-150217.2                                      |
| Build Type        :- IKAP - (Production)                                    |
| UserID            :- SWIFTAMHMQ                                             |
| Process Name      :- E:\MQServer\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin64\amqrmppa.exe        |
| Arguments         :- -m SWIFTBACK
Major Errorcode   :- rrcE_BAD_DATA_RECEIVED                                
| Minor Errorcode   :- OK                                                     |
| Probe Type        :- MSGAMQ9207                                             |
| Probe Severity    :- 2                                                      |
| Probe Description :- AMQ9207: The data received from host '10.51.13.23' on  |
|   channel '????' is not valid
```

This is written in FDC file. I couldn't understand what invalid data means. Is it message size or message character?

Is there a message format? What is format and how to check it?

MQ client version 8.0.0.2

It is new issue, previously this channel was working fine, it's production server. After restarting queue manager and application, this issue got resolved.
What formats of messages do we have, can you please explain this?

@ Hi all
can any one please help on this,

What formats of messages do we have, can you please explain this?

Comment: Can you provide output of `DIS CHS(CHLNAME) RPRODUCT RVERSION` while the channel is in RUNNING status? What specific v8.0 is the client? Is it a new problem? Did it ever work?

Comment: Now that the channel is running can you provide the output of `DIS CHS(CHLNAME) RPRODUCT RVERSION` replacing `CHLNAME` with the name of the `SVRCONN` channel.

Comment: You should have a look at [this link](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?p=71651&sid=b76d0a87b10a450022992b73aad2f48d) which refers to the same issue.

Comment: Note that the link is related to a problem in 2004, it was solved by a patch to a version of MQ that has not been supported or updated since 2003.  The OP stated the version in use was v8 which is a current version and the linked thread would not apply to it.